# Adding alert with Greasemonkey on site using Socket.IO

Tags: javascript, socket.io, greasemonkey

I want to create a Greasemonkey script that will pop up an alert when a specific message is received from the site through it's Socket.IO data transport. The site in question is [bittrivia.com](http://bittrivia.com/) and playing around with the Firefox web console I found the object I need to tweak, but I'm not getting the expected results. I want to make it alert whenever the question is updated (and because there are limits on free play, a simple timer won't suffice), so I can do some work in between questions. This is what I have so far, but I never see any of the messages printed to the console.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name    BitTrivia Question Alerts
// @include https://www.bittrivia.com/*
// @require http://userscripts.org/scripts/source/100842.user.js
// @run-at  window-load
// ==/UserScript==

contentEval(function() {
    // Not sure if it's a timing issue, so try waiting for it to become available.
    function whenAvailable(callback) {
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            if (undefined === io.sockets)
                whenAvailable(callback);
            else  callback();
        }, 100);
    }
    whenAvailable(main);

    function main() {
        var socket = io.sockets['https://s1.bittrivia.com:80'];
        console.log(socket);
        socket.on('message', onMessage);
    }

    function onMessage (packet) {
        console.log(packet);
        var c = BISON.decode(packet);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(c));
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you sure it uses messages?  There are other ways to check for question changes too.  Can poll the question text, for example.

Comment: Yes, it uses messages. If I disable websockets I can see the response data using HttpFox when it falls back to xhr-polling. You're right that polling for text would probably work for this specific case, though I was hoping to figure out the more generic method of looking at the messages so I could use the same method with other sites and for more complex actions.